# bash record output to file of npm test terminal results

Tags: reactjs, bash, npm

I run

> CI=true npm test > testRestults.txt

OR

> CI=true npm test | tee testRestults.txt

in react frontend project. It prints the following to the terminal

```
> todo-frontend@0.1.0 test
> react-scripts test

PASS src/Todos/Todo.test.js
  √ renders text (43 ms)
  √ renders correct button text (8 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.345 s
Ran all test suites.
```

but it only saves

```
> todo-frontend@0.1.0 test
> react-scripts test
```

to the testRestults.txt file. How do I get it to record the entire output?